# How to search keywords using "And" clause in database : LINQToSQL

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I developed a search functionality recently which searches database on EnglishValue column in Tag table.   I recieve list of Keywords from search box and i search it using following query and it gives me correct results.

```
List<string> keywords = new List<String>(searchText);


IQueryable<Tag> tags = from p in db.Tags
                       where keywords.Contains(p.EnglishValue)
                       select p;

var matchingTagList = tags.ToList();
```

Now one of the ask is to search using "AND", currently LINQ query is doing OR. If any one can give suggestions how to do AND search using LINQToSQL that will help.

I am adding more details on how my database looks like.  If i seach for Pet-Friendly and Wi-Fi than i should get Id= 1.

[image: Database Table]

Comment: The reverse of `Contains(..)` is `All(..)`

Comment: What would be the meaning of inserting the `AND`? A single `EnglishValue` cannot equal all of the keywords at the same time, unless all keywords happen to be the same (which is nonsense).

Comment: We need some clarification, because from how your question is phrased I'm not sure that this LINQ query is doing what you want.  Are you after something like this `SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE EnglishValue = @keyword1 OR EnglishValue = @Keyword2 ... etc` or like this? `WHERE EnglishValue LIKE '%' + @keyword1 + '%' OR EnglishValue LIKE ... etc`

Comment: It would make more sense to search for e.g. posts having _any_ or _all_ tags in `keywords`. Is that what you're actually doing (without showing it to shorten the code)?

Comment: To avoid confusion i have added my database table. I am trying to search on database column using And criteria.

Comment: This only adds confusion. How does `Pet-Friendly and Wi-Fi` result in 1? You highlight 1 and 11. (Why not 2 and 6?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<string> keywords = new List<String>(searchText);    

IQueryable<Tag> tags = from p in db.Tags
                        where keywords.All(x=> p.EnglishValue.Contains(x))
                        select p;

var matchingTagList = tags.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this. That why I love LINQ. Assuming you keyword is containing the term and also some varialble here called Num =5;

```
List<string> keywords = new List<String>(searchText);


IQueryable<Tag> tags = from p in db.Tags
                       where keywords.Contains(p.EnglishValue) && p.num==5
                       select p;

var matchingTagList = tags.ToList();
```